# Criar um Contador incrementando um Digito separado a cada 60 segundos

Tags: javascript

Como não tenho muito conhecimento de javascript gostaria de uma ajudinha de como fazer esse script a baixo.

Esse script seria um contador onde a cada 60 segundos soma-se pontos
e esse contador comece da data e hora x a data e hora fim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se é isso que deseja:

```js
var cont = 0;
var pontos = 0;

function contador() {
  document.getElementById('tempo').innerHTML = cont;
  if(cont == 60){
    cont = 0;
    pontos++;
    document.getElementById('pontos').innerHTML = pontos;
  }
  cont++;
  setTimeout("contador()", 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
  //Insere as datas de inicio e fim do contador.
  var datainicio = '03/04/2019 00:00:00';
  var datafim = '05/04/2019 00:00:00';

  var hoje = new Date();
  var dd = String(hoje.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(hoje.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = hoje.getFullYear();
  var hh = String(hoje.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
  var MM = String(hoje.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
  var ss = String(hoje.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');

  hoje = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + hh + ':' + MM + ':' + ss;

  if(hoje >= datainicio && hoje <= datafim){
    contador();
  }
}
```

```html
<b>Tempo: </b><span id="tempo">0</span></br>
<b>Pontos: </b><span id="pontos">0</span>
```

Comment: show... isso mesmo só não poderia zerar se realizar uma atualização

Comment: Você terá que trabalhar com banco de dados para esse tipo de gravação, caso eu te ajudei marque como resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: eu pensei em pegar os segundos atuais date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); $hora = date('H:i:s'); pegando a hora atual com segundo atual

Comment: tipo a contagem começa-se a partir da horario e segundo atual   não daria pra fazer assim ?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, tente ser um pouco mais claro no que você precisa.

Comment: Então exemplo a contagem começaria em 01/04/2019 as 12:00:00  até 05/04/2019 12:00:00. sabemos que esse intervalo  tem 5760 minutos que seria os "Pontos" . seria fazer o calculo de minutos  entre as datas e horário mostrando sempre um cronometre atualizando os pontos que na verdade seriam os minutos

Comment: https://www.topster.pt/calendario/zeitrechner.php?styp=zeit&sdatum=2019-04-01&szeit=12%3A00%3A00&typ=zeit&edatum=2019-04-05&ezeit=12%3A00%3A00&subDazu=%2B&jahredazu=0&wochendazu=0&tagedazu=3&zeitdazu=00%3A00%3A00

Comment: No caso você quer um contador de minutos restantes entre duas datas?